# How to pull text from the selected TextBox on a Report? VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013, ms-access-forms, ms-access-reports

I have a Report (rptCourses) which contains 170 TextBoxes which contain Course names, pulled from an access Table (tblCourses). When the user clicks on one of the Course Name TextBoxes, a form (frmRateCourse) loads containing a TextBox (txtboxCourseTitle), essentially a header, which ideally would contain the Course Name of the selected Report TextBox.

My question is: How can I take the text from the selected Report Textbox and input that text into the loaded Form's TextBox?

I apologize if this question already exists! And thank you, in advance, for any assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest is to pass the string as `OpenArgs`.

```
Private Sub CourseName_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmRateCourse", OpenArgs:=Me.CourseName.Value
End Sub
```

and in frmRateCourse:

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    Me.lbTitle.Caption = Nz(Me.OpenArgs, "<no Title>")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked exactly how I wanted it to. I’m fairly new to this and teaching myself as I go along. Didn’t think to use OpenArgs